# Xcode iPhone X - how to return to black bands

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-x

These days I'm doing an iOS application with swift. The problem is that I anchored everything with the height and length of the screen, so it comes out different. I would like to have the black bands above and below so, as to return to 16:9.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: deactivate the safe area in your storyboard

Comment: are you sure that it work?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend fixing an application's size to 16:9, this will provide a bad user experience for iPhone X users.

Comment: are you using launch Screen StoryBoard ?

Comment: IOS Geek how can I see that?

Comment: I still can't figure out why do you want that. Instead you should be adopting changes and update your app to support Safe area. Like the4kman said, this is bad user experience.

Comment: Can I change the color of the bands?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions?  Flying blind here.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your constraints on your view.  Then add them back making sure you are pinning the top and bottom to the Safe Area like so (red view for emphasis):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> For apps with custom layouts, supporting iPhone X should also be
>   relatively easy, especially if your app uses Auto Layout and adheres
>   to [Safe Area](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/) and margin layout guides.

Answer (score 0):

a Working solution from my current App

when I dont make use of kaunchScreen.storyboard

output:
[image]

As you are having black area in iPhone X Same is here

**Solution**

[image]

**Output after solution**

Black area is removed

[image]

**Hope it Helps**

Comment: do your splash screen Designed in Launch screen Storyboard appears correctly in iPhone X? or that is also created programmatically and you haven't designed Splash using launch SCreen storyBoard